# Changing "New Item" Text

Tags: javascript, 2013

I want to change the "New Item" text into "Yeni Ekle". I viewed the source of the list from browser. Here is the part of the New Item;

```
<a id="idHomePageNewItem" ...........>
  <span ...>
    <img id="idHomePageNewItem-img" ....></img>
  </span>
  <span>  new item  </span>
</a>
```

And here is my code for change the text. But it doesn't work. Why doesn't it work?

**Updated:**

```
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:RssLink runat="server"/>
    <SharePoint:scriptlink ID="ScriptLink" Name="SP.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" Localizable="false"></SharePoint:ScriptLink> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/../../../Style Library/SolidQ-SPS-JS.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ChangeText,"sp.js");
        function ChangeText() {
          document.getElementById('idHomePageNewItem').getElementsByTag("span")[1].innerHTML="Yeni Ekle";
        }
    </script>
</asp:content>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try change `getElementsByTag` to `getElementsByTagName` as that is the valid Javascript DOM selector

So the solution script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ChangeText,"sp.js");
    function ChangeText() {
      document.getElementById('idHomePageNewItem').getElementsByTagName("span")[1].innerHTML="Yeni Ekle";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple reasons, either your javascript is executing before the control text has been rendered, or your selection method is not correct.

Have you tried triggering the function manually after the page has fully loaded from the console?

Comment: Doesn't $().ready trigger the function?

Comment: Well it does, but it has a tendency in sharepoint to trigger before all sharepoints javascript functions has executed. I usually use ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded() and specify sp.js or sp.ui.socialribbon.js as the script to wait for just to make sure

Comment: I updated the javascript part. It doesn't work. Did I write it wrong?

Comment: Yes, you should only write the functions name as the first parameter in ExecuteOrDelay.. Like ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ChangeText,"sp.js");

Comment: Should I import anything for sp.js?

Comment: sp.js should be added by Sharepoint OOTB

Comment: I updated script part in the question again. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Well you are still using an incorrect bracket "{" instead of "(" when you trigger "ExecuteOrDelay"

Comment: I correct it but still nothing.

Comment: And console says nothing? Can you see that the script function is actually on the page and try triggering manually? If it is, and still nothing happens, then I guess you need to look over your DOM selection

Comment: The problem is document.getElementById.. When I put an alert instead of it, it works but changing text doesn't work.